# Словарь из слов ООП

Tags: c#

Задание вот такое:

> Создать программу обработки текста учебника по программированию с
>   использованием классов: Символ, Слово, Предложение, Знак препинания
>   (состав и иерархию классов продумать самостоятельно).

Я новичок в ООП, и не понимаю принципиально, как это сделать.
Поясню, если бы я это делал без использования классов, то я бы парсил строки в массив, потом из них выделял бы слова(сканированием до символа ' '), ну и там уже опять, же с помощью массивов записывал бы повторения и сами слова.
Но как тут использовать, классы с#?
Я создал классы: строка, слово, символ, ок, а что с ними делать дальше?)
Я не прошу писать мне код, это без толку, мне важно понять сам принцип, что и как мы это делаем. Спасибо.

Comment: интересный вопрос, но причем тут словарь указанный в заголовке?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вероятно так: базовым классом сделать "Символ" со свойством типа `char`, далее производным от него "Знак препинания" (где нужно выставить ограничение на char которые относятся к знакам препинания) и второй производный класс "Буква" (где нужно выставить ограничение на char которые относятся к буквам). Создаем класс "Слово", у которого `List<Буква>`, ну и "Предложение" которое содержит свойства типов `List<Знак препинания>` и `List<Слово>`. Навскидку так, еще нужно подумать о хранении места положения слова в предложении, символа в слове, знака препинания в предложении, позиции предложения в тексте.

Answer (score 3):

Формальное описание текста на естественном языке штука очень сложная, особенно если учесть всякие особенности языка, вроде сокращений, многозначного использование знаков препинания, сложно-всякие предложения и т.д. не считая  ошибки и опечатки. Поэтому без контроля со стороны оператора, обработка произвольного текста задача практически невыполнимая.

**@Bulson** предложил вариант разработки иерархии снизу-вверх, так что я попробую предложить вариант сверху вниз, истина где-то посередине.

**Текст** в простом случае - массив **предложений**, порядок следования задается порядком размещения в массиве.

**Предложение** состоит из **лексем** - минимальных самостоятельных осмысленных единиц текста.

**Лексемы** можно разделить на 3 класса: **разделитель** (пробел), **знак препинания**, **слово** (слово из одной буквы тоже слово, число записанное цифрами - тоже слово). Каждая **лексема** - один и более **символов** из группы, заданной для данного типа лексем.

**Символ** - минимальная единица текста, строительный кирпич для лексем, в принципе можно использовать базовый `Char` для этого.

Ну и самое важное, на мой взгляд, прописать формальные правила для текста, например: предложение не может начинаться и заканчиваться разделителем, в конце предложения должен быть знак препинания, слово не может начинаться с символа обозначающего знак препинания, но может содержать его в середине или конце (сокращения т.е., т.к., инициалы и подобное), ну и т.д. и т.п.

Причем никакой иерархии классов тут не будет, тут будет композиция, вместо наследования. Хотя в отдельных случаях применение наследования возможно, например для лексем.